# Цикл в функции не заканчивается

Tags: c++, функции, циклы

По условию задачи нужно вывести логарифм по основанию 2 от числа. Но в функции где-то бесконечный цикл. Помогите его найти.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int log(int x) {
    int k = 0;
    do {
        x/2;
        k++;
    }
    while (x >= 2)
    return k;
}

int main() {
    int c, a, p;
    cin >> c; //тут я ввожу 5, т.к. по заданию нужно найти 5 логарифмов
    for (int i = 0; i<c; i++) {
        cin >> a; //само число, от которого нужно найти логарифм
        p = log(a);
        cout << p << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы делите `x` на два, но тут же отбрасываете результат. Замените `x/2` на `x/=2`.

Comment: x/2 - может, должно быть x=x/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
do {
    x/2; 
    k++;
}
while (x >= 2)
```

У вас в функции значение `x` не изменяется - результат деления не присваивается ничему...

Наверное, вы хотели написать `x/=2` ? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 do {
    x/2;
    k++;
}
```

`x/2` думаю у тебя должна присваиваться) `x = x/2;`